# Stopping a continuous Event in C# with (f.ex.) a button

Tags: c#, process

This is probably simple, and the question might not be very good, but I'm looking for the best or most efficient way to accomplish this:

1. A button click starts an Event, which then runs a method that continiously pings an IP address. The ping output is displayed in a text box.
2. A click on the same button stops the ping task.

Here's the (I think) relevant code:

The method run by the Event connected to the Ping button:

```
private void pingClicked (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    pinger();
}
```

The pinger() method:

```
private void pinger() {
    string command = "/c ping " + ipadrtextbox.Text;

    if (contchkbox.Checked) {
        command += " -t";
    }

    ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD", command);

    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    proc.Start();
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += new 
    DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);

    proc.Start();

    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
}

void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Data != null) {
        string newLine = e.Data.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
        MethodInvoker append = () => pingoutput.AppendText(newLine);
        pingoutput.BeginInvoke(append);
    }

}
```

A while-loop in the pinger method results in a complaint that "An async read operation has already been started on the stream.", so that's apparently not the way to go.

Also, I haven't found a way for the method to listen for a buttonpress elsewhere in the application, and then stop the task with roc.CancelOutputRead(). But I expect that's the way the task should be stopped?

Comment: Keep your process as a property and close it on your second button tap.

Comment: You should prrhaps use the .net framework for ping

Comment: I'm sure that' a better solution. At this moment I'm just trying to get a basic grasp on C# and Windows. Coming from a Linux/Unix C/C++ world, this is how I would've done it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the running process as a `private` member of your class then:

```
private void pingClicked (object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if( process != null && !process.HasExited )
     {
         process.CancelOutputRead()
         process.Kill();
         process=null;
     } else {
            pinger();
     }
 }
```

Comment: If I declare the process with "private Process proc;" outside of the pinger method, then create it with "proc = new Process();" inside the pinger method, the application works as before. When I click on the button a second time, it just starts a new ping process. However, if I add an else-block after your if-block, and use "proc.CancelOutputRead();" instead of "proc.kill()", it seems to work.

Comment: @FrankH. sorry, forgot the else  :)

Comment: And the "process.CancelOutputRead()" instead of "process,Kill()" :-) But the solution works.

Comment: If you update your post, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: @FrankH. did you try to leave the kill after CancelOuputRead? I think it would be cleaner

Comment: Yes, it apparently works identically. But I guess maybe Kill() is cleaner. But even after process.Kill(), proces.Hasexited reports false, so I'm not sure if it actually kills the process?